# Department or department?

Tags: american-english, british-english, capitalization

I have been asked to review a document but I have a dilemma:
"D" in below phrase should be capital?

**"It can flourish collaboration among the members of the Department"?**

Or job title:

**"The Chairperson of Department is responsible for ...."**

**"You should focus to support our Research Chairs"**

These sentences are from a formal proposal (statement) and I believe that non of the words should have the first-letter capitalized.

Although these are not proper name, the author capitalized first-letter of the job title and the words:"Department" and "Chairperson" all over the document. 
I do not feel confident enough that they should be kept capitalized or not.

Comment: You've got more problems than just capitalisation. All your examples look like "unnatural" phrasing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more problems with the sentences than just incorrect capitalizations. No, „department“ should not be capitalized. Plus I would drop the capitalization of „research chair and add „the“ „chairperson of THE department, not just „chairperson of department“, that is incorrect grammatically.

Grammatical errors (very obvious): 1. Flourish is strictly an intransitive verb. That means it NEVER can take an object. Things can flourish (no object) but no one can „flourish“ something. That´s impossible. You cannot „flourish collaboration“. That´s not an English sentence. You can encourage/ support/promote collaboration but never „flourish“ it. That´s just an incorrect verb -object match. Whoever wrote that needs to pick an appropriate verb that correctly matches „collaboration“. This is just sloppy and incorrect English. No native speaker would make these obvious errors. Never.

2. „You should focus to support (sic) our research chairs.“ No. That won`t work. The preposition that matches (properly goes with) „focus“ is ON, not TO. You focus ON something, not „to“ something in English.

Comment: Please note that in English, quote marks should all be ‘high’. Even opening quote marks aren’t written at the bottom, where commas and full stops go.